# "craft" a response vs "draft" a response

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between the following two expressions: **craft** a response and **draft** a response?

Note. Not directly related, but I found the following information on the *usage frequency* of these two expressions interesting:

- [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=craft%20a%20response%2C%20draft%20a%20response&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccraft%20a%20response%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraft%20a%20response%3B%2Cc0) says "craft a response" is more common than "draft a response"
- [Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/%5Bcraft+draft+%5D+a+response) says "draft a response" is more common than "craft a response"

Note. While online dictionaries have entries for the individual words "craft" and "draft", they do not include the above expressions/collecations. Sometimes the meaning of a word depends on whether it is used individually or in combination with others. That is why I wanted to get clarification from a native speaker.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to show that you've looked both words up in a dictionary, what you found, and what questions remain.

Comment: @AndyBonner Does the note I recently added at the end of the question serve the purpose?

Comment: Which word you pick depends on what you want to convey, hence the importance of understanding the differences in the definition. That you have looked at the definitions doesn't help us understand what you concluded from the differences. "I want the opinion of a native speaker" looks like a proofreading request, which is off-topic here. Andy is giving you advice that will help your question stay open and get good answers.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you for the feedback. I further modified the note at the end of the question to clarify the reason why I decided to post the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *craft* something is to create it, with care.

To *draft* something is to make a preliminary version, or a rough copy of a text that may be subject to amendment.

So the two are quite different - one suggests that enough care and attention is going into it that it may not need further amendment.

Comment: (Just to avoid confusion, worth pointing out that the OP is using verbs for both, even if the verb meaning of *draft* is just "to create [the noun meaning]")

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks, the verb definition still supports this, I've amended so they match.